# dayhourminsec countdown plugin working in Chrome but not in firefox, IE

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have this simple script in jquery to run-

```
var date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
var n = date.toISOString();

alert(n);
```

But instead it returns error: **Uncaught TypeError: date.toISOString is not a function**

I want to convert the date string into ISO date format which is compatible with firefox. However its not working in Jquery. Is there a different function for ISO date format conversion for Jquery or is there any error in my script or toISOString works only for javascript not jquery?  I

Answer (score 0):

Here's a polyfill from the mozilla [developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
  (function() {

    function pad(number) {
      if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
      }
      return number;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
      return this.getUTCFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
        'T' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) +
        '.' + (this.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        'Z';
    };

  }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add

> new Date()

for toISOString to run

```
var date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'; // This will not work to run toISOString

var date = new Date('2016-01-01 00:00:00');  //This will do the job 
var n = date.toISOString();
alert(n);
```